# Should I repeat "one" here?

Tags: repetition

I've started to describe a problem that way:

> On my computer, I have two Angular projects:
> the first is an Angular 14 one, linked to Java

Should I repeat *one* a second time?

> the first one is an Angular 14 one, linked to Java

or simplify my sentence with:

> the first one is Angular 14, linked to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose your simplified version, because "one" might be seen as another number after "Angular 14".

Did you mean to say "one **in** Angular 14"?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, also for `in`.